# Rails Load a icon which isn't saved in the images folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, directory

I wand to give a preview of the just uploaded pictures. These pictures are not saved in the public folder, as they are not public...

How can I do this?

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create a Controller to send_file ( http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_file ) it.

```
class AvatarsController

  def show
    send_file my_avatar_path, :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline'
  end
end
```

In this controller you can add all authorization you want.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately there doesn't get any data loaded:

Comment: send_file path, :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline' (I made sure that the path is wright!)

Comment: It works now as I use send_data instead... strange! does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1) Create symlink to the images in
    the public folder?

2) As you are
    using the images publicly, they
    should really be in the public
    folder - why are they currently not?

Comment: no they are not public! the only get showed to the user who upload the image... thanks for your answer, I will prove the symlink hint!

Comment: I think the answer with the controller is probably the best approach